# Theme does not take post format file from child theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I have "post-format" .php file in theme. (templates/blog/). I want to change some thing in this file so that need to add this in child theme.

In child theme, I created folder (templates/blog/) and then paste file. As per my research, I added below code in child theme function.php. Function called proper. but when I run it always take post-format.php file from parent theme instead of child theme.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'setup_postformats', 10);
//add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'setup_postformats', 20);
//add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'setup_postformats', 11);

function setup_postformats(){
    remove_theme_support('post-formats');
  add_theme_support('post-formats',  array( 
     'aside', 
     'chat', 
     'gallery', 
     'image', 
     'link', 
     'quote', 
     'status', 
     'video', 
     'audio'
  ));
}
```

Theme Name - Lincoln
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to set the priority for your after_setup_theme higher than your parent theme. The default priority is 10. Using the `twentysixteen` as example, use priority 11 on child themes. `'after_setup_theme'` action. Please refer to the below example:

```
function twentysixteen_child_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array(
        'video',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twentysixteen_child_setup', 11 );
```

**Update**

```
// in your Child Theme's functions.php    

// Use the after_setup_theme hook with a priority of 11 to load after the
// parent theme, which will fire on the default priority of 10
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_post_formats', 11 ); 

function remove_post_formats() {

    remove_theme_support( 'post-formats' );
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'video' ) );
}
```

Comment: Actually I had already tried 11 but forgot to specify in question. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the code for include the **post-format.php** in child theme **functions.php** file. So it will take the child theme version of **post-format.php**.

Hope this will solve your issue.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: I tried - include 'post-format.php'; or include 'templates/blog/post-format.php' - In both cases single post page get post format file from parent theme. And even another page in child theme doesn't work proper if I add this.

Comment: Theme name - Lincoln

Comment: Theme is in Themeforest and seems will work good with it. You can try Plugin to create child theme and test your code. https://wordpress.org/plugins/orbisius-child-theme-creator/

Comment: Also try your old code by deleting the post-format.php file from parent theme. Please take backups before doing it.

Comment: I delete file post-format.php file from parent theme but still it doesn't get post-format file from child theme. If I use this plugin then do I need to remove my child-theme first that I have created in normal way?.

Comment: Actually Plugin will make the child theme in proper way, which I assume that current one is not. As I am not able to see what you exactly happening your end, its very difficult to say anything accuratly

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I take backup of current child theme then I activate plugin.

Comment: Activated plugin - Child theme created - Added code in function.php - Added file child theme (post-formats.php) but still it doesn't get from child theme.

Comment: Now please add the include code in child theme and delete the code and file from parent theme and try it again.

Comment: No, After creating child theme from plugin, then I added post-format file in child theme and removed from parent theme. But it still gets post-format file from parent theme.

Comment: No. It shows error - File not found in parent theme. It means it's going to parent theme instead of child theme.

Comment: are you working in localhost or in any url which can be shared with me

Comment: I am working on live but I have deactivated plugin now.

Comment: Which plugin? Orbitiuos is only to create the child theme once. Can the url and code be shown to me

Comment: deactivated Orbitiuos plugin and it's created child theme. Then again added child theme there as it was. I am going somewhere now and I will give you URL later surely.

Comment: OK, will check once you send